# How can I run Django unit test in Microsoft TFS automatically?

Tags: django, tfs, django-unittest

How can I run **django unit test** in **Microsoft TFS** automatically?

Answer (score 0):

By default the Python-Django test feature is not integrated in TFS.

However vNext build (TFS 2015 and later) have more flexible steps, so you can use the [Command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=vsts) task or [Utility: Batch script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/batch-script?view=vsts) task to run pytest or django test. That means if you can run the Django unit test in command line, then you can run the tests in TFS.

Please reference this article to do that:  [Running Python Unit Test in a VSTS/TFS build](https://adventuresinscm.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/running-python-unit-test-in-a-vststfs-build/)

Other articles for your reference to run the Django unit test:

- [Writing and running tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/)
- [DJANGO UNIT TEST CASES WITH FORMS AND VIEWS](https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-unit-test-cases-with-forms-and-views/)
- [Setting a Full Testing Framework for Django (and more!)](http://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/tools/setting-a-full-testing-framework-for-django-and-more.html)

Besides, you can also have a try for this extension : [Python Test](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dazfuller.pyunittest-task)